# Swagger send and receive array

Tags: swagger, swagger-3.0

```
openapi: "3.0.0" 
info:   
  title: project 
servers:
- url: http://example1.net/v3
- url: http://example/v3

paths:

  /Pn/{PnId}/service1:
    post:
      summary: Pn data
      description: |
        can Pn the data
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/dataInfo"
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/dataInfo"
      parameters:
      - name: PnId
        in: path
        description: PnId
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pn"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: status
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/dataInfoStatus"
              example: infoable
        default:
          description: error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"

components:   
  schemas:
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
        message:
          type: string
      required:
      - message
    Pn:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    dataInfo:
      type: string
    dataInfoStatus:
      type: string
      enum: [infoable, non_infoable,ignorable]
```

I am sending a single dataInfo in request and getting single dataInfoStatus in response, but I will like to send and array of dataInfo and get an array of dataInfo status.

I tried following:

```
schema:
  type:array
  items:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/dataInfo"
```

but I get

> Parser error bad indentation of a mapping entry

for items. I am following [this](https://swagger.io/specification/).

How can I achieve sending dataInfo in request as an array of dataInfo and getting in response an array of dataInfoStatus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one more space between `type:` and `array`, then the error message is gone:

```
schema:
    type: array
    items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/dataInfo"
```

And you can add the `info.version` for the [version of the openapi file](https://swagger.io/specification/#info-object).

Comment: Thanks that resolved the error :) . "And you can add the info.version for the version of the openapi file" , could not follow this ? ( I have mentioned the version openapi: "3.0.0"  above, if that is what you meant .

Comment: If I used the [editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) I get a error `missing property` because I do not set the [version of the file](https://swagger.io/specification/#info-object).